# GCC/Clang: disable tail recursion optimization for single function

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, clang, tail-recursion

I understand I can disable tail recursion optimization in GCC with the option `-fno-optimize-sibling-calls`. However, it disables the optimization for the whole compilation unit.

Is there a way to disable the optimization for a single function?

It is my understanding that I can change the function so it's not a valid candidate for tail recursion - say, by using the return value in an expression so the return is not the last instruction in the function. E.g.:

```
return f(n) + 1;
```

The solution above may still be optimizable, though, and future (or current, I don't know) versions of the compiler may be smart enough to make it into a tail call - say, by changing

```
int f(i) {
  if(!i) return 0;
  return f(i - 1) + 1;
}
```

into

```
int f(i, r = 0) {
  if(!i) return r;
  return f(i - 1, r + 1);
}
```

I'm looking for a cleaner and future proof solution that doesn't require changing the algorithm, if at all possible.

Looking through the documentation I couldn't find a function attribute or built-in that does that, but my search hasn't been exhaustive.

Comment: _"... it disables the optimization for the whole compilation unit.."_ move the function into it's own file.

Comment: That would work if the function is not inline or a template.

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: Curiosity. Why? What's the upside of disabling it?

Comment: Assume I have a good reason. I don't want to derail the conversation into whether or not the reasons for wanting it are legitimate or not. If all you're looking for are constraints for the solution, say I need independent stack frames for each function call.

Comment: Independent stack frames are a reason enough, but wouldn't you want them for all functions?

Comment: No, just for hand picked special functions. The rest of the code should be optimized as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use the GCC-specific `#pragma optimize()` directive ([combined with suitable bracketing with push/pop `#pragma` lines](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html#Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas)) to achieve a result similar to specifying a function attribute:

```cpp
#pragma GCC push_options // Save current options
#pragma GCC optimize ("no-optimize-sibling-calls")
int test(int i)
{
    if (i == 1) return 0;
    return i + test(i - 1);
}
#pragma GCC pop_options  // Restore saved options

int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    int j = test(i);
    return j;
}
```

But note that clang doesn't support this form of `#pragma optimize`. Also, note this warning [from the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-optimize-function-attribute):

> Not every optimization option that starts with the -f prefix specified
> by the attribute necessarily has an effect on the function. The
> optimize attribute should be used for debugging purposes only. It is
> not suitable in production code.

Answer (score 0):

`__attribute__((__optimize__("no-optimize-sibling-calls")))` appears to work on GCC.

Clang gives `warning: unknown attribute '__optimize__' ignored`.